# How can I search automatically for values and variables in Firebug/Script/Watch?

Tags: firebug

I'm looking at an extensive webapp and I want to find a particular object. I set a breakpoint to inspect available variables and I have some educated guesses as to what property values are defined by the object or what kind of selfdocumented variable names could have been used for the object. Instead of tediously/manually searching the tree structure in the Script/Watch tab, is there an automated search feature by which I can search for all variables and values that are available to me at the current scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature doesn't exist in Firebug.